# Taurus YAML - Ho to write Compute Concatenation var (suffix _ALL)

Tags: jmeter-5.0, taurus

JMeter JSON Extractor has

[image: JSON Extractor]

How should I write this in Taurus YAML:  `Compute concatenation var (suffix _ALL)`???

In Taurus Documentation I have found this:
[image]
[image: Taurus Documentation]

To get the value of that variable with suffix _ALL, it creates variable: `planIds_ALL`, it contains all the values for the extracted regex.
can I get help on how should I write that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working through Taurus YAML.
We have to write:  `concat: true`
and the variable will have suffix `_ALL.`

`in my case: ${planIds_ALL}`